# Getting error while creating pdf using html-pdf node package and Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices in Azure web app

Tags: node.js, pdf, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, html-pdf

I trying to create PDF using html-pdf nod package and .net core mvc application. Its working fine in local. When deploying to Azure web app i am getting below error.

**In web page:**

> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host Unknown location

---

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Azure web app console:**

```
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Node\createPdf.js:5
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:         stream.pipe(result.stream);
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:                ^
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:     at D:\home\site\wwwroot\Node\createPdf.js:5:16
2019-11-22 06:39:58.754 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:     at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\html-pdf\lib\pdf.js:58:21
2019-11-22 06:39:58.755 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:     at respond (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\html-pdf\lib\pdf.js:126:14)
2019-11-22 06:39:58.755 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:     at Timeout.execTimeout (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\html-pdf\lib\pdf.js:91:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to sandbox restrictions. You may leverage Azure App Service Container based on your requirement.

The standard/native Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available- [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#general-sandbox-restrictions).

So, essentially Azure App Service provides pre-defined application stacks on Windows like ASP.NET or Node.js, running on IIS. The preconfigured Windows environment locks down the operating system from administrative access, software installations, changes to the global assembly cache, also it does not allow the registration of COM components on the platform. and so on. If your application requires more access than the preconfigured environment allows, you can deploy a custom Windows container instead.

Checkout these documents for more details on this topic:

[Run a custom Linux container in Azure App Service](http://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker)

[Run a custom Windows container in Azure (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container)